# Why is RTTI bad? (dynamic_cast <-> qobject_cast)

Tags: c++, qt, rtti, dynamic-cast

The Qt documentation says the following:

> The `qobject_cast()` function behaves similarly to the standard C++ `dynamic_cast()`, with the advantages that it doesn't require RTTI support and it works across dynamic library boundaries.

Why is it better to use `qobject_cast` over `dynamic_cast`, what's wrong with RTTI? Should I always prefer to use `qobject_cast` when I'm dealing with `QObject` inherited objects?

Comment: Some compilers allow you to disable RTTI in which case `dynamic_cast` won't work. But since `qobject_cast` presumably uses its own system for tracking real time type information, it should still work. But I find it hard to imagine a case where you would want to disable RTTI but still being able to accommodate Qt.

Comment: OT: I have run into several problems on windows where qobject_cast does not work but dynamic_cast works fine. I believe it has to do with a combination of static and dynamic libraries and crossing library boundaries  however I did not investigate the root cause.

Comment: Sounds mysterious to me. If I want to use RTTI functionality, I should do it in a portable way. Switching off C++ language features and use some home brew stuff seems not the right way to me. Independent what you use, you have to pay for it. RTTI is not bad, it simply costs. If you need it, pay it and use it.

Comment: In the case of `qobject_cast`, you're already paying for it: every Qt object has a `virtual metaObject()` that returns a `QMetaObject*`. The latter has lots of methods for reflection and even a `bool inherits(const QMetaObject *metaObject) const` that `qobject_cast` presumably uses internally.

Comment: Re: "works across dynamic library boundaries" -- if RTTI gets screwed up by the use of dynamic libraries, then it's implemented wrong.  So, yes, this could be a workaround for a (major) compiler bug.

Comment: @Pete-Becker: The no-rtti version dates back when compilers had exactly such problems. Nowadays this option is still available for low-end systems to avoid runtime overhead due to rtti.

Comment: @chehrlic -- yes, implementors provide non-standard language versions for various mostly not-so-good reasons.